# pst-jtree; pstricks: Drawing a box around three nodes

Tags: pstricks, linguistics, pst-jtree

I want to draw a box around part of a syntax tree I'm typesetting using `pst-jtree`. Here's a simplified example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}

\begin{document}
    \jtree[scaleby=1.5 1]
        \! = {S}
            :{NP}! {VP} "{\psset{scaleby=1 1}}
            :{V}(<vert>{saw}) {NP}@NP "{\psset{scaleby=0.75 1}}
            :{D}(<vert>{the}@the ) {N}(<vert>{cat}@cat ).
        \! =:{D}(<vert>{The}) {N}(<vert>{dog}).
        \ncbox[nodesep=5pt, linearc=0.2]{the}{cat}
    \endjtree
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

However, what I would like is for the top of the box to include the NP node as well, like this (created using image editing software):

[image]

However, I can't seem to find a way to fit a box around three nodes using `pstricks`. What would be ideal is if there's something along the lines of the functionality provided by `tikz`'s `fit` library to do this. (Marking text in the tree as tikz nodes doesn't work, since the tikz node coordinates are always at the top of the bounding box.) Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: This is built into `forest` but, yes, that's `tikz` again ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}

\begin{document}
    \jtree[scaleby=1.5 1]
    \! = {S}
    :{NP}! {VP} "{\psset{scaleby=1 1}}
    :{V}(<vert>{saw}) {NP}@NP "{\psset{scaleby=0.75 1}}
    :{D}(<vert>{the}@the ) {N}(<vert>{cat}@cat ).
    \! =:{D}(<vert>{The}) {N}(<vert>{dog}).
    \psframe[framearc=0.2,linestyle=dashed](!\psGetNodeCenter{the} the.x 0.5 sub the.y 0.5 sub)
      (!\psGetNodeCenter{NP} \psGetNodeCenter{cat} cat.x 0.5 add NP.y 0.6 add)
    \endjtree
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 So there still are some PSTricks wizards around! This seems like a more general approach, although it requires raw postscript code.  Not for the faint of heart, though.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, it's *so* much easier to draw trees with `forest`. But if you insist, with a little hacking it can be done. There are very few `pstricks` wizards around these days, and it's a long time since I've used it, so I certainly don't qualify.

I've added the `forest` version for comparison.

Gratuitous linguistic comment: lines between terminal nodes and their category labels aren't syntactically sensible, so all of the `<vert>` on terminal nodes should be removed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}


\begin{document}
    \jtree[scaleby=1.5 1]
        \! = {S}
            :{NP}! {VP} "{\psset{scaleby=1 1}}
            :{V}(<vert>{saw}) {\Rnode[href=-2]{NP}{NP}}@NP "{\psset{scaleby=0.75 1}}
            :{D}(<vert>{the}@the ) {N}(<vert>{cat}@cat ).
        \! =:{D}({The}) {N}(<vert>{dog}).
        \ncbox[nodesep=5pt,boxsize=3,offset=1.5,linearc=.5]{the}{NP}
    \endjtree
    
\begin{forest}
[S
    [NP [D\\the] [N\\dog]]
    [VP [V\\saw]
        [NP,tikz={\node[draw,rounded corners,fit to=tree]{};} [D\\the][N\\cat]]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]